# ADB commands for SPP-RFCOMM testing

Tags: testing, bluetooth, adb, rfcomm, spp

I'm conducting bluetooth protocol testing on an Android 2.3.3 phone.
 I have the device in USB debugging mode connected to my windows 7 PC, using cmd to fire commands to the device.

The problem: I'm unable to figure out how to submit an SDP-query. Let me set the scene, the test case:
 "Verify that the IUT establishes a connection to an emulated serial port in the Tester. The IUT is a device taking on the role as DevA. The Tester is Acceptor"... n.b. the tester is the test machine that the android device (IUT) should be talking to.

The first step, which is where i'm stuck: "Submit a query using SDP to find out the RFCOMM Server channel number of the desired application in the remote device. This might include a browsing capability to let the user select among available ports (or services) in the peer device. Alternatively, if it is known exactly which service to contact, it is sufficient look up the necessary parameters using the Service Class ID associated with the desired service."

The device:
 Stock - don't know how to root the device lol!
 Not overclocked.
 Bluetooth 2.1 version 1.0.46.0

So far i've tried the following.
 Enter the adb shell, 
rctest -u [BT address of test machine] , sometimes i get 'can't connect, now in progress' or 'cant connect to host' and even regardless of running the test case or not.
 also tried: rctest -u [BT address of test machine] and it will indefinitely wait on channel 10 :S
sdptest -i B  : Can't connect to SDP service: Host is down

I just think im missing something big which is preventing me from progressing any further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding is correct, u want to look the rfcomm channel number using SDP, if that's correct and you are having a phone with bluez stack, try for sdptool browse, it will search for all the devices nearby and will update the SDP record of the available devices .